# Node.js - Can't play .wav audio file converted from base64

Tags: node.js

By referring the following link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291593/convert-base64-audio-to-file), I have converted base64 to .wav audio file. But it's not playing in any application except VLC media player.

Can anyone provide me the solution for this.

Client side code:

```
 const audioBlob = new Blob(this.audioChunks, { 'type': 'audio/wav' });
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(audioBlob); 
reader.onloadend = function() {
    var base64data = reader.result;                
    resolve(base64data);
}
```

Server side code:

```
var fs=require('fs')
//Here base[1] is my base64 data
fs.writeFileSync(filename, Buffer.from(base[1].replace('data:audio/ogg; codecs=opus;base64,', ''), 'base64'));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you're writing a WAV file, but the metadata suggests it's an OGG file.

Comment: Even I tried with the following statement, fs.writeFileSync(filename, Buffer.from(base[1].replace('data:audio/wav; codecs=pcm;base64,', ''), 'base64'));

Comment: You should check what `base[1]` _actually_ starts with.

Comment: "data:audio/wav; codecs=pcm;base64,GkXfo59ChoEBQveBAULygQRC84EIQoKEd2VibUKHgQRChYECGFOA......" . This is how base[1] value starts with, if I use data:audio/wav