# How to get meta data from base64 audio data

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, base64

My backend will take a base64 audio data then it must check the number of seconds in the audio data ,

in case - that's hard to do directly , my idea is to create a temporary normal audio file , and store it in my local server then read the meta-data from it

I searched and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48291710/10614290) , but did not work with me ,
the file created but - when I opened it , it has ZERO number of seconds (seems damaged)

that's the code I tried to create the file locally then read the meta-data from it :

```
fs.writeFileSync('file.ogg', Buffer.from(base64data.replace('data:audio/ogg; codecs=opus;base64,', ''), 'base64'));
```

I'm expecting to have runnable audio file and then read the data from it - but the actual created file is damaged

if there's anyway to fetch the number of seconds in the audio from the base64 data directly - it will be very good

Comment: can you post your encoded data somewhere so we can debug your problem?

Comment: also https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-buffer-from might help you

Comment: @DominicWehrmann ,I tried the library - it seems still does not work =
that's the base64 data I'm trying to convert https://www.mediafire.com/file/9gbk9b989o1xq5s/data.txt/file