# How to convert a web audio blob to playable .wav or .mp3 file in node.js server?

Tags: node.js, audio, server, blob, webm

I am setting up a node server to record microphone audio and save it to use in a sonic installation. I can get the files, but they are not really .wav, so I can't play the audio files on my own computer. Any ideas on how to convert the audio to .wav or even mp3?
I really appreciate any help!

server side:

```
app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
  readdir(messageFolder)
    .then(messageFilenames => {
      res.status(200).json({ messageFilenames });
      let totalFiles = messageFilenames.length; // return the number of files
  console.log(totalFiles); // print the total number of files
   myID = totalFiles + 1;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error reading message directory', err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});

app.post('/messages', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.message) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No req.body.message' });
  }    
//the problem must be in this line?
 writeFile(messageFolder + "sound" + ".wav", req.body.message, 'base64')
 .then(() => {
      res.status(201).json({ message: 'Saved message' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error writing message to file', err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

---

client side:

```
saveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(audio.audioBlob);
  reader.onload = () => {
    const base64AudioMessage = reader.result.split(',')[1];

    fetch('/messages', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: base64AudioMessage
      })
    }).then(res => {
      if (res.status === 201) {
        return populateAudioMessages();
      }
      console.log('Invalid status saving audio message: ' + res.status);
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Before we can recommend a way to convert the data into a wav or mp3 we need to find out what kind of response data you get (mp3, wav, binary, base64, etc).

Can you give us more information about the post request data that is being sent to the /messages endpoint?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question with that part of the code.

Comment: You might have to find out if its a mp3 wav or ogg. But I think your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291593/convert-base64-audio-to-file?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert base64 audio to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291593/convert-base64-audio-to-file)

Comment: Actually I tried to do what they suggested in the post, but got stuck.
this part should be in the client-side script: 
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onloadend = () => {
  var base64data = reader.result;}

but this on the server-side: 
fs.writeFileSync('file.ogg', Buffer.from(base64data.replace('data:audio/ogg; codecs=opus;base64,', ''), 'base64'));

this may be a newbie question, but how to make the server script access the base64data variable in the other one? I just get 'undefined'.